# Error when trying to create a new user in Parse for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

When I try to signup a new user, I get the error

`No supported account linking service found`

Here is my signup method

`public void createUser(View view) {
        String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();

```
    // Set up a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_signup));
    dialog.show();

    // Set up a new Parse user
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);

    // Call the Parse signup method
    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (e != null) {
                // Show the error message
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Start an intent for the dispatch activity
                //Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, DispatchActivity.class);
                //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "You signed up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}`
```

Here is my application:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    // Initialize Crash Reporting.
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "O4oL0sDxJz6tWKT7JqKJ7iaQ46kU356oMCWzLCkv", "QktMk3l5KKFYv1nna0dnYzmnHxHzeyqIaCOKVSod");


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

I don't want to link with anything, I just want to save a ParseUser.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check to see if the automaticUser is logged in (or anyone else):

```
  //Check if anyone is signed in
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            //Logged in, do something
        } else {
            //No user, create one
        }
```

Also:

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();  //Will make app bug out
```

This is why, as you launch the app it thinks there is a user already logged in. Cheers

Comment: I get the exact same error with that line commented out.

Comment: Thank you for the edit!  It turns out, that even without the enableAutomaticUser, there was still a currentuser at the start.  If I log him out, I can create a new one.  Do you have any idea where this user is coming from?

Comment: That's the autoUser. The app ran, enabled an auto sign in and thus gave you a currentUser. Without calling ParseUser.logout(); the user is retained until the schema is rebuilt.